# Unable to clear Browser cookies and Session Data with Selenium

Tags: java, android, session, selenium-webdriver, appium

I have been using `Java` `Selenium WebDriver` along with `Appium` to perform tests on Mobile environment be it `Emulator(Genymotion)` or Physical devices (`Android`). I am using `chromedriver`, which I am using to perform tests on Web App in Chrome browser. I am looping my cases for multiple sets of data but the application requires a full browser Cookie and all Session data to be deleted before each loop starts.
I tried using `driver.Manage().Deleteallcookies()`, but it did not work out for me. I read in some threads to try creating a new session of the browser before each loop. So I tried `driver.quit()` but it ends the `chromedriver` session and ends the test. I also tried `driver.close()` but got the same results as `driver.quit()`.
Can any one suggest a way to delete the browser cookies and session data in `chrome` browser??

> My Appium version:1.3.4.1
>   Chromedriver version:2.3
>   Device/Emulator i am trying to test on : Nexus5/Samsung Note 3 Android:4.4.4/5.0

Comment: `driver.Manage().Deleteallcookies()` should do it and when yo say it did not work what do you mean? Can yo provide any stacktrace of the error?

Comment: The command runs properly without an error but the session data and the local storage data in the browser is not deleted. They are retained. But when I clear all browsing data manually all data is deleted.

Comment: Are you talking about browser cache?

Comment: Yes. I am talking browser cache and cookie storage.

Comment: `Deleteallcookies` will not clear out the browser cache.

Comment: Can you suggest any java command that will do the job.

Comment: Can you please tell me how do you instantiate the driver?

Comment: DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities().android();

Comment: capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", deviceName);
                                capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
                                capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "4.4.4");
                                capabilities.setCapability("browserName", "chrome");
                                capabilities.setCapability("udid", device);

driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://16.155.189.53:4444/wd/hub"),capabilities);

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the following to ensure a clear session. Note I never tested that myself. My understanding is that selenium by default create a new session unless you specified something different or load a profile.

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ForSeleniumServer.ENSURING_CLEAN_SESSION, true);
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

Comment: I tried the above code but this also gave the same result. For a fresh flow everything is ok but problem is in the 2nd flow, where the session data breaks the functionality. 
The above code is not deleting the session data.

Comment: @Vir Are you running the second session with same driver instance?

Comment: Yes the same instance

Comment: I am afraid @Vir but then the above code will not work since you are not executing them on second run,

Comment: Is there any other way out

Comment: Can I trigger a new instance of Chromedriver for every iteration without ending the test

Comment: try `
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.SUPPORTS_APPLICATION_CACHE,false);` instead